# Reading variable length binary values from a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binaryfiles

I have three text values that I am encrypting and then writing to a file. Later I want to read the values back (in another script) and decrypt them.

I've successfully encrypted the values:

```
cenc = rsa.encrypt(client_name.encode('utf8'), publicKey)
denc = rsa.encrypt(expiry_date.encode('utf8'), publicKey)
fenc = rsa.encrypt(features.encode('utf8'), publicKey)
```

and written to a binary file:

```
licensefh = open("license.sfb", "wb")
licensefh.write(cenc)
licensefh.write(denc)
licensefh.write(fenc)

licensefh.close()
```

The three values cenc, denc and fenc are all of different lengths so when I read the file back:

```
licensefh = open("license.sfb", "rb")
encMessage = licensefh.read()
```

encMessage contains the entire file and I don't know how to get the three values back again.

I've tried using a separator between the values:

```
SEP = bytes(chr(0x02).encode('utf8'))
...
licensefh.write(cenc)
licensefh.write(SEP)
...
```

and then using encMessage.partition(SEP) or encMessage.split(SEP) but the data invariably contains the SEP value in it somewhere (I've tried a few different characters) so that didn't work.

I tried getting the length of the bytes objects cenc, denc and fenc, but this returned 256 for each value even though the contents of the variables are all different lengths.

My question is this. How do I write these three variable length values to a binary file and then separate them when I read them back again?

Here's an example of the 3 binary values:

```
b'tX\x10Fo\x89\x10~\x83Pok\xd1\xfb\xbe\x0e<a\xe5\x11md:\xe6\x84@\xfa\xf8\xe5\xeb\xf8\xdc{\xc0Z\xa0\xc0^\xc1\xd9\x820\xec\xec\xb0R\x99/\xa2l\x88\xa9\xa6g\xa3\x01m\xf9\x7f\x91\xb9\xe1\x80\xccs|\xb7_\xa9Fp\x11yvG\xdc\x02d\x8aK2\x92t\x0e\x1f\xca\x19\xbb&\xaf{\xc0y>\t|\x86\xab\x16.\xa5kZ"\xab6\xaaV\xf4w\x7f\xc5q\x07\xef\xa9\xa5\xa3\xf3 6\xdb\x03\x19S\xbd\x81\xf9\xc8\xc5\x90\x1e\x19\x86\xa4q\xe3?i\xc4\xac\t\xd5=3C\x9b#\xc3IuAN,\xeat\xc6\x96VFL\x1eFWZ\xa4\xd73\x92P@\x1d\xb9\x12\x15\xc9\xd4~\x8aWm^\xb8\x8b\x9d\x88\n)\xeb#\xe3\x93\xb1\\\xd6^\xe0\xce\xa2(\x05\xf5\xe6\x8b\xd1\x15\xd8v\xf0\xae\x90\xd8?\x01\r\x00\xf4\xa5\xadM|%\x98\xa9SR\xc6\xd0K\x9e&\xc3\xe0M\x81\x87\xdea\xcc\xd5\x9c\xcd\xfd1l\x1f\xb9?\xed\xd1\x95\xbc\x11\x85U9'    

b'l\xd3S\xcc\x03\x9a\xf2\xfdr\xca\xbbA\x06\xfb\xd8\xbbWi\xdc\xb1\xf6&\x97T\x81Kl\r\x86\x9b\x95?\x94}\x8a\xd3\xa1V\x81\xd3]*B\x1f\x96`\xa3\xd1\xf2|B\x84?\xa0\ns\xb7\xcf\x18Y\x87\xcfR\x87!\x14\x81!\xf7\xf2\xe5x|=O\xe3\xba2\xf2!\x93\x0fT7\x0c~4\xa3\xe5\xb7\xf9wy\xb5\x12FM\x96\xd9\xfd\xedn\x9c\xacw\x1b\xc2\x17+\xb6\x05`\x10\xf8\xe4\x01\xde\xc7\xa2\xa0\x80\xd8\x15\xb1+<s\xc7\x19\x9c\x14\xb0\x1a"\x10\xbb\x0f\xe1\x05\x93\xd2?xX\xd9\x93\x8an\x8d\xcd\xbd!c\xd0,\xa45\xbai\xe3\xccx\x08\xaa,\xd1\xe5\'t\x91\xb8\xf2n$\x0c\xf9-\xb4\xc2\x07\x81\xe1\xe7\x8e\xb3\x98\x11\xf3\xa6\xd9wz\x9a3\xc9\x9c?z\xd8\xaa\x08}\xa2\x9c[\xf2\x9d\xe4\xcdb\xddl\xceV\x7f\xf1\x81\xb3\x88\x1e\x9c5?k\x0f\xc9\x86\x86&\xedV.\xa7\x8d\x13&V\xad\xca\xe5\x93\xfe\xa5\x94\xbc\xf5\xd1{Cl\xc0\x030\x92\x03\xc9'

b'#\xbdd7\xe9\xa0{\t\xb9\x87B\x9e\xf9\x97P^\xf3V\xb6\x93\x1f(J\x0b\xa3\xbf\xd8\x04\x86T\xa4\xca\xf3\xe8%\xddC\x11\xdb5\xff,\xf7\x13\xd7\xd2\xbc\xf3\x893\x83\xdcmJ\xc8p\xdf\x07V\x7fb\xeb\xa9\x8b\x0f\xca\xf9\x05\xfc\xdfS\x94b\x90\xcd\xfcn?/]\x11\xaf\xe606\xfb\\U59\xa0>\xbd\xd8\x1c\xa8\xca\x83\xf4C\x95v7\xc6\xe00\xe4,d_/\x83\xa0\xb9mO\x0e\xc4\x97J\x15\xf0\xca-\xa0\xafT\xe4\x82\x03\n\x14:\xa1\xdcL\x98\x9d,1\xfa\x10\xf4\xfd\xa0\x0b\xc7\x13!\xf7\xdb/\xda\x1a\x9df\x1cQ\xc0\x99H\x08\xa0c\x8f9/4\xc4\x05\xc6\x9eM\x8e\xe5V\xf8D\xc3\xfd\xad4\x94A\xb9[\x80\xb9\xcf\xe6\xd9\xb3M2\xd9N\xfbA\x18\x84/W\x9b\x92\xfe\xbb\xd6C\x85\xa3\xc6\xd2T\xd0\xb2\xb9\xf7R\xb4(s\xda\xbcX,9w\x17\x1c\xfb|\xa0\x87\xba\xca6>y\xba\\L4wc\x94\xe7$Y\x89\x07\x9b\xfe\x9b?{\x85'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read from binary file with variable length records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835417/read-from-binary-file-with-variable-length-records)

Comment: @JawandS. what if the OP just knows about Python ?

Comment: okey got the bottom line is it true ? You'd need to know how the file was written out in the first place.

Comment: reading a big file in binary with custom line terminator and writing in smaller chunks in python_   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45888081/reading-a-big-file-in-binary-with-custom-line-terminator-and-writing-in-smaller

Comment: add a struct at the beginning of the file that holds the lenght of the 3 values ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@pippo1980 's comment is how I would do it, using [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) :

```py
import struct

cenc = b'tX\x10Fo\x89\x10~\x83Pok\xd1\xfb\xbe\x0e<a\xe5\x11md:\xe6\x84@\xfa\xf8\xe5\xeb\xf8\xdc{\xc0Z\xa0\xc0^\xc1\xd9\x820\xec\xec\xb0R\x99/\xa2l\x88\xa9\xa6g\xa3\x01m\xf9\x7f\x91\xb9\xe1\x80\xccs|\xb7_\xa9Fp\x11yvG\xdc\x02d\x8aK2\x92t\x0e\x1f\xca\x19\xbb&\xaf{\xc0y>\t|\x86\xab\x16.\xa5kZ"\xab6\xaaV\xf4w\x7f\xc5q\x07\xef\xa9\xa5\xa3\xf3 6\xdb\x03\x19S\xbd\x81\xf9\xc8\xc5\x90\x1e\x19\x86\xa4q\xe3?i\xc4\xac\t\xd5=3C\x9b#\xc3IuAN,\xeat\xc6\x96VFL\x1eFWZ\xa4\xd73\x92P@\x1d\xb9\x12\x15\xc9\xd4~\x8aWm^\xb8\x8b\x9d\x88\n)\xeb#\xe3\x93\xb1\\\xd6^\xe0\xce\xa2(\x05\xf5\xe6\x8b\xd1\x15\xd8v\xf0\xae\x90\xd8?\x01\r\x00\xf4\xa5\xadM|%\x98\xa9SR\xc6\xd0K\x9e&\xc3\xe0M\x81\x87\xdea\xcc\xd5\x9c\xcd\xfd1l\x1f\xb9?\xed\xd1\x95\xbc\x11\x85U9'
denc = b'l\xd3S\xcc\x03\x9a\xf2\xfdr\xca\xbbA\x06\xfb\xd8\xbbWi\xdc\xb1\xf6&\x97T\x81Kl\r\x86\x9b\x95?\x94}\x8a\xd3\xa1V\x81\xd3]*B\x1f\x96`\xa3\xd1\xf2|B\x84?\xa0\ns\xb7\xcf\x18Y\x87\xcfR\x87!\x14\x81!\xf7\xf2\xe5x|=O\xe3\xba2\xf2!\x93\x0fT7\x0c~4\xa3\xe5\xb7\xf9wy\xb5\x12FM\x96\xd9\xfd\xedn\x9c\xacw\x1b\xc2\x17+\xb6\x05`\x10\xf8\xe4\x01\xde\xc7\xa2\xa0\x80\xd8\x15\xb1+<s\xc7\x19\x9c\x14\xb0\x1a"\x10\xbb\x0f\xe1\x05\x93\xd2?xX\xd9\x93\x8an\x8d\xcd\xbd!c\xd0,\xa45\xbai\xe3\xccx\x08\xaa,\xd1\xe5\'t\x91\xb8\xf2n$\x0c\xf9-\xb4\xc2\x07\x81\xe1\xe7\x8e\xb3\x98\x11\xf3\xa6\xd9wz\x9a3\xc9\x9c?z\xd8\xaa\x08}\xa2\x9c[\xf2\x9d\xe4\xcdb\xddl\xceV\x7f\xf1\x81\xb3\x88\x1e\x9c5?k\x0f\xc9\x86\x86&\xedV.\xa7\x8d\x13&V\xad\xca\xe5\x93\xfe\xa5\x94\xbc\xf5\xd1{Cl\xc0\x030\x92\x03\xc9'
fenc = b'#\xbdd7\xe9\xa0{\t\xb9\x87B\x9e\xf9\x97P^\xf3V\xb6\x93\x1f(J\x0b\xa3\xbf\xd8\x04\x86T\xa4\xca\xf3\xe8%\xddC\x11\xdb5\xff,\xf7\x13\xd7\xd2\xbc\xf3\x893\x83\xdcmJ\xc8p\xdf\x07V\x7fb\xeb\xa9\x8b\x0f\xca\xf9\x05\xfc\xdfS\x94b\x90\xcd\xfcn?/]\x11\xaf\xe606\xfb\\U59\xa0>\xbd\xd8\x1c\xa8\xca\x83\xf4C\x95v7\xc6\xe00\xe4,d_/\x83\xa0\xb9mO\x0e\xc4\x97J\x15\xf0\xca-\xa0\xafT\xe4\x82\x03\n\x14:\xa1\xdcL\x98\x9d,1\xfa\x10\xf4\xfd\xa0\x0b\xc7\x13!\xf7\xdb/\xda\x1a\x9df\x1cQ\xc0\x99H\x08\xa0c\x8f9/4\xc4\x05\xc6\x9eM\x8e\xe5V\xf8D\xc3\xfd\xad4\x94A\xb9[\x80\xb9\xcf\xe6\xd9\xb3M2\xd9N\xfbA\x18\x84/W\x9b\x92\xfe\xbb\xd6C\x85\xa3\xc6\xd2T\xd0\xb2\xb9\xf7R\xb4(s\xda\xbcX,9w\x17\x1c\xfb|\xa0\x87\xba\xca6>y\xba\\L4wc\x94\xe7$Y\x89\x07\x9b\xfe\x9b?{\x85'

packing_format = "<HHH"  # little-endian, 3 * (2-byte unsigned short)

with open("license.sfb", "wb") as licensefh:
    licensefh.write(struct.pack(packing_format, len(cenc), len(denc), len(fenc)))
    licensefh.write(cenc)
    licensefh.write(denc)
    licensefh.write(fenc)
# close is automatic with a context-manager

with open("license.sfb", "rb") as licensefh2:
    header_length = struct.calcsize(packing_format)
    cenc2_len, denc2_len, fenc2_len = struct.unpack(packing_format, licensefh2.read(header_length))
    cenc2 = licensefh2.read(cenc2_len)
    denc2 = licensefh2.read(denc2_len)
    fenc2 = licensefh2.read(fenc2_len)
    assert len(cenc2) == cenc2_len and len(denc2) == denc2_len and len(fenc2) == fenc2_len  # the file was not truncated
    unread_bytes = licensefh2.read()  # until EOF
    assert len(unread_bytes) == 0  # there is nothing else in the file, everything has been read

assert cenc == cenc2
assert denc == denc2
assert fenc == fenc2
```

Comment: Thanks, never ever used a struct other than dev/rfkill in a kali linux distros, it's nice to learn with examples. Would your example works on any platform or shoud I use packing_format = "@HHH"  to be sure my script could be universally portable ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the [byte order](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment), but according to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55164136/differences-in-pythons-packed-binary-data-size-among-platforms#comment97067866_55164136) using one of `<` or `>` forces to use this one independently from the platform's endianness, while `@` guarantees nothing. I'm not sure how it would work if the file was copied from one arch to another, but my guess is that forcing it makes it safer.

Comment: I tought @ was for platform default, didnt know it doesnt guarantees, tx again

Comment: @pippo1980 sadly I don't have any big-endian system at hand to check, and I couldn't find any online Python interpreter which would be big-endian

Comment: wish I could be able to do that: https://www.reddit.com/r/mainframe/comments/2yusvz/took_90_minutes_to_boot_but_here_is_an_emulated/

Comment: Many thanks, your answer worked like a dream.

Comment: Tried the code and works fine, but the header in our case is not needed all tre var are 256 of lenght and can be read 256 for each one. I like the idea that the header was a possible call to solve the problem of 'Reading variable length binary values from a file in python'

Comment: Indeed the three are of length 256 ! I did not noticed it because the lengths in the file are different, but that's just randomly caused by mixing printable ASCII characters with `\xAB` escape codes which takes more visual space. If the length is known beforehand, then one can just do `cenc = licensefh.read(256); assert len(cenc)==256` three times and be done.